# How can I set AutoHotKey's code to run only in chrome?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to simulate a "find" operation when I double click a word in Chrome.

I've managed to do this :

```
~LButton::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome
If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<400) and (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<>-1)
{
 SendInput ^c
 Sleep, 10
 SendInput ^f
 Sleep, 10
 SendInput ^v
}

Return
```

But it runs even for  non-chrome process (when double click a word)

**Question:**

How can I make this script run only when double click in chrome ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Chrome.exe ;; start of IfWinActive condition, for me it didn't work with ahk_class so i changed it to ahk_exe
~LButton::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  
If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<400) and (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<>-1)
{
SendInput ^c
Sleep, 10
SendInput ^f
Sleep, 10
SendInput ^v
}
Return

~RButton::
SendInput {Escape}
Return
#IfWinActive ;; end of condition IfWinActive
```

Comment: Thanks. Works. is it possible to add to that same script a trigger on right click ? I mean how would it look like ?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean? You want to add so it works if you double click and/or if you press right click? Or you want it so when you right click the hotkey toggles on or off?

Comment: I want to add to the same script , a code so that if I right click , it should  invoke sendInput "escape". But i dont know how to "add" another condition . There is a goto label here named lbutton. How can i add another one for right click?

Comment: As far as I understand you this is it. This are regular hotkeys no labels included. There are hotkey,if conditions that use labels but they are slightly different.

Comment: Oh I thought that `~RButton::` is a goto label . Thank you BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title of the window or active window with WinGet - and then only apply the code IF that given window is active.

SetTitleMatchMode, 2

## IfWinActive, - Google Chrome

This is a snippet I found:

```
DetectHiddenText, On ; the url of the active Chrome window is hidden text...
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow ; ...we also need match mode 'slow' to detect it
; activate chrome window,
; just for demonstation:
WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; we only want to check for the hidden text if Chrome is the active window,
{
WinGetText, wintext, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; if it is we grab the text from the window...
If InStr(wintext,"autohotkey.com")   ;       ...and if it contains a url that we want,
{
;### code conditional on url goes here ###
msgbox % "The active Chrome window is on the autohotkey.com domain! The page title and URL is:`n`n>" wintext                                 ; <<== we run the desired code here.
}
}
exitapp
```

but it needs to be changed to fit your specific needs.

Comment: I've tried it , but still it reacts to every program i double clikc https://pastebin.com/HBzz3SVP